# How to compile PHP to make it independend from system libraries?

Tags: php, configuration, compiler-construction, shared-libraries

I need a standalone independent-from-system-libraries version of PHP to be able to distribute it as a .zip file containing binaries. Previously the .zip was containing libxml2.so.2, libpng12.so.0, php.ini and php executable. 
Recently I needed to add some functionalities and recompile the PHP. I did it with:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/home/user/php/out \
    --libdir=. \
    --enable-static=YES \
    --enable-shared=NO \
    --with-pdo_mysql \
    --with-gd \
    --with-mysql \
    --enable-zip \
    --enable-zend-multibyte \
    --enable-cgi \
    --enable-fastcgi \
    --with-ldap=shared
make && make install
```

Then I took php from out/bin and libmysqlclient.so.16 from /usr/lib/. But the new php doesn't want to pick up the library. Once I run it I get the following error:

```
./php: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libmysqlclient.so.16 and php are in the same directory. If i put libmysqlclient.so.16 to /usr/lib, php works fine.

Is there any additional option that I've forgotten about during compilation? Why isn't the "--libdir=." option working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the directive is `--with-libdir` not `--libdir`. Second, I think it is relative to `/usr`, so putting `.` there means you need to put the shared libraries into `/usr`.

If you have done any C coding with shared libraries, you must know about `ld`. The easiest way to handle shared libraries path is to use `ld`.

You can set the library path for the current (shell) session:

```
bash-4.1$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/libs
```

You can also configure `ld` to do it all the time:

```
bash-4.1$ echo /path/to/your/libs >> /etc/ld.so.conf
bash-4.1$ ldconfig
```

Comment: It was just enough to start PHP with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\`pwd\` ./php` - thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use XAMPP and save yourself sometime? It comes prepackaged and pretty portable.

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html